# understanding use_count with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I came up with the following example

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> a(new foo());
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> b = a;
    std::cout << "before" << b.use_count() << "\n"; //returns 2
    b.reset();
    std::cout << "after" << b.use_count() << "\n";  //returns 0
} 
std::cout << "Finished\n";
```

Now in the above code the second `use_count` statement returns zero.
In that case isnt the destructor suppose to be called before printing out `"Finished"`. Why is use_count in the second statement printing 0 ?
I read that the definition of use_count is:

> Returns the number of shared_ptr objects that share ownership over the
>   same pointer as this object (including it).

If I did a `reset()` before use count that simply means that its reference count decreased by 1. Please correct me If I am wrong.

Here is my understanding of what is going on please correct me if I am wrong

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> a(new foo());   //reference count is 1
{
    std::shared_ptr<foo> b = a;      //reference count becomes 2
    std::cout << "before" << b.use_count() << "\n"; //returns 2 //OK this I understand
    b.reset(); //b smart pointer gives up its reference count so now it should be 1.
    std::cout << "after" << b.use_count() << "\n";  //This should be 1 why is it 0 ?
} 
std::cout << "Finished\n";
```

So my question is why is `b.use_count()` returning 0 ?

Comment: What does `b` share with anyone else after you've reset it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `b.reset();`, `b` is *empty* (i.e. does not point to any object).

According to the standard (quoted from N4527 §20.8.2.2.5[util.smartptr.shared.obs])

> ```
> long use_count() const noexcept;
> ```
>
> 7 Returns: the number of `shared_ptr` objects, `*this` included, that *share ownership* with `*this`, **or `0`
>   when `*this` is *empty***.

Answer (score 2):

A shared pointer is a concept in C++ where you can have multiple pointers to an object in different scopes and only until the last scope returns your share pointer will be invalid, a unique pointer can only be passed to a function using std::move() because of it's definition, a unique pointer implies single ownership on that object that is being pointed to. Now since you have a share_ptr a(new foo()), and then you assign that to b, once reset is called on that b shared_ptr type, b isn't valid and therefore returns zero, however if you do the operation use_count() on a, you will get a result of 1 after reseting b.